# How to grow aquatic floating bladderworts from seed?

Tags: germination, carnivorous-plants, pond

Along with my previous question about *Sarracenia*, I'm also thinking of growing floating *Utricularia* (bladderworts) in the pond. Still not quite decided on the species (there are invasive issues to consider), but I am looking at suppliers. If I chose seed instead of plants, how would I germinate them?

Would getting a jar of pond water (should be full of microbes and daphnia) and dropping the seeds in, be sufficient? I don't want to drop them straight in the pond, because I think the fish will eat the seeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently trying to germinate bladderwort from seed.  I prepared a very moist soil less mix in a plastic transparent egg carton and put them under indoor lights.

Six weeks later progress is slow.  The seedlings are one to two millimeters high.

I believe the real difficulty will getting them large enough to out grow the algae that will start growing in a few months on the soil less mix.

Comment: By "soil-less mix" do you mean something like sphagnum or coir?

Comment: @winwaed yes, I do.  Either will do, something poor in nutrients but good in retaining water.